# Multi device hybrid apps support for VS2014 ctp

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-cordova

I tried to install Multi device hybrid apps to VS2014 ctp, but it fails.I checked and those features are installed: "Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8" and "Windows Phone 8.0 SDK"

Does VS2014 ctp support multi device hybrid apps ? If no, when do you plan to implement or is there an early beta version available for testing ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-Device Hybrid Apps preview is only available for Visual Studio 2013 (Update 2). While there isn't an exact date to make this available for VS "14", you can follow their Twitter (@VSCordovaTools) for updates.

Comment: The vsix extension is installed without problems, but I get some errors in activitylog.xml while debugging. I will wait, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is now included with Visual Studio 2015 and you can install it separately from VS 2015 here: http://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs